# Can I have a Cargo workspace with two binaries relying on a library where only one binary enables a feature of the library?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo workspaces project with the structure:

```
├── src
├── lib
│   └── Cargo.toml
├── tools
│   ├── src/bin/foo.rs
│   └── Cargo.toml
└── Cargo.toml
```

`.`, `lib` and `tools` are my three workspace members. `lib` has a feature that enables tracing of the execution of a performance-sensitive function. As this feature adds performance overhead, the main binary should not enable it, but the `foo` binary is a testing tool which uses it.

However, Cargo workspaces take the union of the features of the two binaries, so the main binary ends up including the feature anyway.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I deliberately [create a subdirectory](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/tree/main/compatibility-tests) that is [excluded from the workspace](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/blob/83fc90c0914b3761d3b7449befbd40a102f2a2ff/Cargo.toml#L74-L76) to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster How do you run the binaries with this method? It would be ideal if I could still do `cargo run --bin foo`.

Comment: There's no great solution for that; I change into the appropriate directory and run the code. One potential thing you could do would be to follow the pattern of [cargo-xtask](https://github.com/matklad/cargo-xtask) and create your own shim binary that just chains off to calling `cargo` in your subdirectory. That might look like `cargo run-tool foo`.

Comment: Ultimately, you are saying that you want to compile one crate in multiple different ways, inside of a technique that is deliberately designed to reduce multiple compilations of a crate; the two are incompatible.